# build.sbt: cannot resolve symbol inThisBuild

Tags: scala, sbt

this is my build.sbt snippet:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  enablePlugins(ScalaxbPlugin).
  settings(inThisBuild(List(
   organization  := "com.example",
   scalaVersion  := "2.11.8"
)))
```

it results in:

> cannot resolve this symbol inThisBuild

I am using sbt 0.13.5 which should support inThisBuild, see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Scopes.html#Build-wide+settings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`inThisBuild` is a feature added in sbt 0.13.9](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/tag/v0.13.9)

To use it upgrade your project to at least 0.13.9, or better the latest version (0.13.15 as of this answer).